# increase value of a dictionary using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I would like to write a simple code to store histogram data in a dictionary, I want to use dictionary comprehension build the final histogram dict. in python. I can achieve that in multiple ways as shown in code below but I have a problem with method two, here is how it works:

1. Enumerate the list of random letters to use that index to access a slice of the list starting at the current iteration to the end
2. check if letters exists in the slice
3. if yes, add the letter as index to the dictionary and increase its value by 1
4. if no, add the letter as index to the dictionary and set its value to 1
   my problem is where is this temporary dictionary to add to before the dict. Comprehension is exhausted. I tried the final dict “histogram_dict” but it’s not the same.
   Again, The main goal is to rewrite the first code in terms of dictionary comprehension as in the second code.
   Thanks

> 

```
import random
rnd_letters_list=[chr(random.randrange(97,122)) for i in range(21)]
histogram_dict={}

#=============first method ==============
# for letter in rnd_letters_list:
#     if letter in histogram_dict:
#         histogram_dict[letter]+=1
#     else:
#         histogram_dict[letter]=1
# print(histogram_dict)

#=============second method ==============
histogram_dict={letter: XXX_dict[letter]+=1
                        if letter in rnd_letters_list[indx::]
                        else XXX_dict[letter]=1
                for indx,letter in enumerate(rnd_letters_list)}
print(histogram_dict)

#=============third method ==============
# histogram_dict={letter:rnd_letters_list.count(letter)
#                 for letter in rnd_letters_list}
# print(histogram_dict)

#=============fourth method ==============
# from collections import Counter
# print(dict(
# Counter(rnd_letters_list).most_common()))
```

Comment: just use your regular loop. Comprehension constructs aren't well suited for this.

Comment: _I want to use dictionary comprehension build the final histogram dict._ Why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago. I extendet the counter class.
Counter itself extends the dictionary.

[Counter Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```py
from typing import Counter, Dict


class Histogram(Counter):
    """
    A that saves discrete values for a histogram in an efficient manor.
    """

    def population(self) -> int:
        return sum(self.values())

    def mean(self) -> float:
        population = 0
        average_value = 0
        for key, value in self.items():
            average_value += key * value
            population += value
        return average_value / population

    def y_mean(self) -> float:
        entry_counts: int = len(self.items())
        sum_of_values: int = sum(self.values())
        return sum_of_values / (entry_counts * sum_of_values)

    def median(self, alpha: float = 0.5) -> float:
        position: int = round(alpha * self.population())
        keys = sorted(self.keys())
        for key in keys:
            position -= self[key]
            if position < 0:
                return key
        return float("NaN") 

    def variance(self) -> float:
        pop: int = self.population()
        if pop < 2:
            return 0
        var: float = 0
        mean: float = self.mean()
        for key, value in self.items():
            var += float(value) * ((float(key) - mean) ** 2)
        return var / (pop - 1)

    def normed(self) -> Dict[int, float]:
        dictionary: Dict[int, float] = {}
        population = self.population()
        for key, value in self.items():
            dictionary[key] = value / population
        return dictionary
```

Comment: i would prefer if there was an easier way that doesn't include importing from other modules, my question is : is that possible, that also leads to another question: how can i step in and debug dict comprehension steps one by one ?

Comment: `from numpy import NaN` is totally unnecessary. You just want `NaN = float('nan')`

Comment: I know. It made sense in the context I used the class in.